# List of special characters which should be filtered for web application security

Tags: validation, struts2, security

What are the various special characters to be filtered in validation.xml in order to make a web application secure?

Comment: against all possible attacks like sql injection

Comment: you can't just filter specific chars to prevent sql injection.

Comment: I'm not very sure what are the various hacking methodologies.. :)
I just wanted to know the list that should be avoided to get the best out of this "filtering" technique ;)

Comment: there are plenty of resources. please do a due diligence search and understand the subject to a finer degree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for filtering characters from input data is to protect against a variety of situations where your input data is "mingeled" with control statements in different programming or scripting environments.

The most typical examples is SQL injection and cross-site scripting.
An example of SQL injection is if you create your sql statments like this:

```
sql = "select username where username = '" + username + "' and password = '" + password + "'"
```

and the user submits the username admin' (note the ')

An example of cross site scripting is i.e. a forum where someone creates a comment with this content:

```
"Hi. This is a comment! <script> .. malicious javascript .. </script>"
```

There are several other variants. If you send out email with user generated input someone may i.e. insert email headers in your code. If you use user generated input in a operating system command line (i.e. to change a password) someone may insert other commands as well.

The only secure way to handle this is to never trust user generated input when you create sql statments, create web pages, send out email etc.

However, as a sort of first defence you may in addition to that filter out often used characters that you know users does not need when validating input. A typical list would contain characters like <>\;"&#^'`?%. NB! That is NOT an exhaustive list, just a couple of typical characters from the front of my head.

Answer (score 1):

If your primary concern is things like SQL injections, the best defense is to use parametrized queries.

Unfortunately, the only article that I've used for reference was for iOS and objective-c, but [here's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parametrized_query#Parameterized_statements) the Wikipedia entry on parametrized statements
.